# angular2 npm http 404 with all rc1 packages

Tags: npm, angular

Trying to upgrade to Angular2 rc1, but seems that npm is not able to download the packages:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     "gulp": "3.9.1",
     "gulp-rimraf": "0.2.0",
     "gulp-uglify": "1.5.3",
     "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
     "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
     "gulp-replace": "0.5.4"
   }
}
```

and the output:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/es6-shim
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/reflect-metadata
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/common
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/core
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/router
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/http
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/systemjs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/reflect-metadata
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/common
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'angular/common' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'App'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd ...
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code E404
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/core
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/systemjs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/es6-shim
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/http
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/router
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js
```

All gulp packages are downloaded successfully which tells me my environment is functional. So it must be something with registration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to upgrade your node and npm installations. At least, I was getting the same error just now while using node 0.10 and some similarly ancient version of npm, and now I've upgraded to node 6.0.0 and npm 3.8.6 then everything is working.

Comment: Definitely look up https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8473 if updating to latest version didn't work. I was on Visual Studio and decided to install Node altogether and use that as an external tool instead of the Node that's shipped with Visual Studio and wait for Microsoft to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Try call this:

```
npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8483

Answer (score 0):

Please check `.npmrc` file. It should have `registry = http://registry.npmjs.org` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install by command prompt. 
Go to the root directory and use command : npm install

It should install all the node_module.
It worked for me.